# Getting package org.assertj.core.api does not exist even though I am specifying in my pom, version 3.6.2 while using JDK 1.8

Tags: java, maven, assertj

I am having problem with `Eclipse` using `Maven`. I am getting
`package org.assertj.core.api` does not exist
even though I am specifying it in my `pom.xml`, as version 3.6.2 while using `JDK 1.8.`
How to overcome it ?
`mvn clean install` is failing.

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile
>   (default-compile) on project
>   com.transunion.qa.datahub.ui.java.bdd.serenity: Compilation failure:
>   Compilation failure:
>
> [ERROR]
>   /Users/pnutala/eclipse-photon-workspace/com.transunion.datahub.ui.qc.java.bdd.serenity/src/main/java/com/transunion/qc/steplibrary/datahub/DeCoherentUser.java:[7,35]
>   package org.assertj.core.api does not exist
>
> [ERROR]
>   /Users/pnutala/eclipse-photon-workspace/com.transunion.datahub.ui.qc.java.bdd.serenity/src/main/java/com/transunion/qc/steplibrary/datahub/DeCoherentUser.java:[7,1]
>   static import only from classes and interfaces [ERROR] -> [Help 1]

Tried `Mvn clean install`, and `verify` unsuccessfully.

```
 import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

 @Step
 public void landedOnListPage(String expectedTotle) {

assertThat(currentListPage.getTitle()).containsIgnoringCase(expectedTotle);
```

Comment: Can we see that section of your pom?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It got solved very trivially, by removing the 'test' scope in the pom file for the dependency(this is what I remember after few days!!)

Comment: @PraNuta please provide your pom before and after change so that future readers like me can be benefitted from this.

Answer (score 10):

It got solved very trivially, by removing the 'test' scope in the pom file for the dependency(this is what I remember after few days!!)

Comment: Any library which is used for testing like testNg, assertJ, hamcrest is likely to cause the error because maven central repo sets the <scope> as test by default.

Comment: I have literally spent over two or three weeks trying every imaginable permutation.  Thank-you, thank-you, thank-you!!!